# How String.prototype.trim can handle exceptions independently?

Tags: javascript, trim

I know that I can send only Strings to the trim method to avoid the exception when passing numbers but I want to know how can I handle that from inside the trim method itself.

**this** is an object and I can't know its type whether String or Number.

```
String.prototype.trim = function(){ return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"") }
```

Sure that the below will not work:

```
this = this.toString();
```

**typeof** returns always object.

I am very eager to know how can we achieve that :)

Thanks.

Comment: @Oka as I mentioned in my question, I know how to avoid this exception by sending only string, but I want to understand how to handle objects in prototype properties :)

Comment: What do you mean by _"I want to understand how to handle objects in prototype properties_" ?

Comment: `String.prototype.trim` is supported natively from IE9 and up, there shouldn't be a need to overwrite it at all, and you certainly shouldn't add unexpected behaviour to it. Just make sure you only pass strings

Comment: @Halcyon for example, how to know the type of this, typeof returns always objects, I can't know if I sent string or number

Comment: Right, there is no way to ask an object what it's type is. You can `instanceof`, you can also defer the type by looking at it's prototype-chain. Was that your question?

Comment: @Halcyon: simple, I want to check if (this) is Number to return same value, if it is String to execute the .replace method, so this way I avoid the exception.

Comment: `return typeof this === 'string' ? this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"") : this`

Comment: @moderns it's odd to do it like that. Normally you'd write an implementation for `Number` and a different implementation for `String`. It's a code smell if you need to check the type of a variable to decide what to do with it. Also, shouldn't `trim` on a `Number` just throw an Error since that's not a sensible operation?